# How to configure the LifeStyle based on a marker interface

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, ioc-container

**The question:**

How can I configure the lifestyle of my components using the presence (or not) of a marker interface on each of them ?

My rules are:

- if a component implements *IAutoInstalledComponent* then it must be registered
- if the component implements *ISingletonComponent* then the lifecycle of the component must be *Singleton*
- if a component implements *IAutoInstalledComponent* but not *ISingletonComponent* it will be have a *PerWebRequest* lifestyle

I've seen an "If" method in the ComponentRegistration given in the ConfigureDelegate of the "Configure" method but could not guess nor get documentation about how to use it.

**My current code:**

```
// a marker interface which I implement on my components by convention 
// just to know which components to register
public interface IAutoInstalledComponent
{
}

// a marker interface to say that the lifestyle should be Singleton
public interface ISingletonComponent : IAutoInstalledComponent
{
}

// This is my unique installer 
public class AutoInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
            .BasedOn<IAutoInstalledComponent>()
             // this is what i want to be Singleton when the component (or service) implements ISingletonComponent                   
            .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest)
        );
    }
}
```

**The context:**

Ok, if you have time, here is global explanation of what I'm trying to do. My goal is to do a bulk registration of all the components in the current assembly. But since some components are really slow to initialize (and are totally threadsafe), I want to create only a single instance of them.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't do this, because now you are mixing DI logic with your application. You should try keeping them seperate. Just allow your DI configuration to be tested. This way you can test if a certain component is registered as singleton.

Comment: Actually, in my opinion the DI logic cannot be totally decoupled from my application because my implementation would be drastically different depending on the LifeStyle configuration. The first thing which commes to my mind is about thread safety : a Singleton class need to be thread safe in all it's public instance methods whereas, a Transient or PerHttpRequest can reasonnably be left as not thread safe.

Comment: Decoupling the DI configuration from the application doesn't mean that any configuration should work. Some types are thread-safe, some aren't. These are comments on the usage of such type and the DI configuration should know these details. For instance, in one of my applications, I have an `IHandler<TCommand>` interface and it specifies that implementations don't have to be thread-safe. While configuring the container, we know we can not configure command handlers as singletons.

Comment: I agree with Steven, this is a bad bad idea.

Comment: Steven, what I want to achieve is to formelize the kind of rule you've just given as example : "an IHandler<TCommand> cannot be singleton". But I want it to be done in the code so that I can build a totally automatic component registration. I created the marker interface for exactly that. I understand that this may sounds weird but I'm using an Ioc just to wire things together while using tons of interfaces. I do NOT need to be able to switch from one implementation to another for a given service (so I don't need an external DI configuration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may filter components using Where() according to implemented interfaces

```
            container.Register
            (
                AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
                .Where(c=> c.GetInterface(typeof(LifestyleUponInterface.InterfaceForSingleton).Name)!=null )
                .Configure( c=> c.LifeStyle.Singleton )
            );
            container.Register
            (
                AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
                .Where(c => c.GetInterface(typeof(LifestyleUponInterface.InterfaceForTransient).Name) != null)
                //.If(Component.IsInNamespace("<yourNamespace>"))
                .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Transient)
            );
```